# String whitespace clean up that is not trim

Tags: java, regex, string, removing-whitespace

so I have been looking on here and I can find alot of solutions that either completely remove all white space or just remove spaces, or just remove tabs. Basically what I need/ want is a way to take a string, and turn all double spaces+ or tabs and turn them into a single space. ie

```
String temp = "This is   a     test        for strings";
String result = "This is a test for strings";
```

any ideas? possible java library methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String result = temp.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

where `\\s+` stands for more than one whitespace character.

Comment: two thank yous! 1. Thank you, this is honestly exactly what i wanted. 2. for not making fun

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regExp` with method [`#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) other than that you can *first use* `trim` to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
    String temp = "This is   a     test        for strings";
    String result = temp.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Here `\\s+` is `regExp` which means one or more spaces which will be replaced with single space by `replaceAll` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String temp = "This is   a     test        for strings";
String result = temp.replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
```